# Powershell Pipeline - return a new Object, that was created within pipline

Tags: powershell, hashtable, psobject, pscustomobject

I keep running into the same problem again, and i have my default way of handling it, but it keeps bugging me.
Isn't there any better way?

So basicly i have a pipline running, do stuff within the pipline, and want to return a Key/Value Pair from within the pipline.
I want the whole pipline to return a object of type psobject (or pscustomobject).
Here is the way i do it everytime.
I create a hashtable at the beginning of the pipline and add key/Value Pairs from within the pipline to this hashtable using the .Add() method.
Afterwards i create a psobject by passing the hashtbale to New-Object`s -Property Parameter.
 This gives me the desired result.

```
Get-Process | Sort -Unique Name | ForEach-Object -Begin { $ht = @{} } -Process {
    
    # DO STUFF
    $key = $_.Name
    $val = $_.Id

    # Add Entry to Hashtable
    $ht.Add($key,$val)
}

# Create PSObject from Hashtable
$myAwesomeNewObject = New-Object psobject -Property $ht

# Done - returns System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
$myAwesomeNewObject.GetType().FullName
```

But this seems a bit cluncky, isn't there a more elegant way of doing it?

Something like this:

```
[PSObject]$myAwesomeNewObject = Get-Process | Sort -Unique Name | ForEach-Object -Process {
    
    # DO STUFF
    $key = $_.Name
    $val = $_.Id

    # return Key/Val Pair
    @{$key=$val}
}

# Failed - returns System.Object[]
$myAwesomeNewObject.GetType().FullName
```

This unfortunally dosn't work, since the pipe returns an array of hashtables, but i hope you know now what iam trying to achieve.
Thanks

Comment: Do you specifically want a hashtable-styled psobject, where you change input property values to property names? Compared to using `Get-Process | Sort -Unique Name | Select Name,Id` for example. Your sample would cause overwrites when processes have the same name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is more elegant but just another way of doing it, this uses an anonymous function so `$ht` will no longer be available after execution, and casts to `[pscustomobject]` instead of using `New-Object`:

```bash
[pscustomobject] (Get-Process | Sort -Unique Name | & {
    begin { $ht = @{ } }
    process {
        # DO STUFF
        $key = $_.Name
        $val = $_.Id

        # Add Entry to Hashtable
        $ht.Add($key, $val)
    }
    end { $ht }
})
```

Comment: Great thing about piping to script block instead of using `ForEach-Object` is that the script block doesn't pollute the variables of the parent scope, i. e. `$ht` doesn't exist after the pipeline has finished.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `-End` parameter to convert the final hash table to a pscustomobject as part of the pipeline, without needing to set the whole thing to a variable

`$ht[$key]=$val` is also a nice shorthand for `$ht.Add($key,$val)`:

```
Get-Process | 
  Sort -Unique Name | 
    Foreach -Begin { $ht = @{} } -Process { 
      $ht[$_.Name] = $_.Id 
    } -End {[pscustomobject]$ht} |  
      ## continue pipeline with pscustomobject
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Santiago Squarzon and @Cpt.Whale answers, i were able to combine them to create a solution that pleases me:

```
$myAwesomeNewObject = `
Get-Process | Sort -Unique Name | & {
    begin { $ht = @{} }
    process {
        # DO STUFF
        $key = $_.Name
        $val = $_.Id

        # Add Entry to Hashtable
        $ht[$key]=$val
    }
    end {[pscustomobject]$ht}  
}

# Success - System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
$myAwesomeNewObject.Gettype().FullName

# And helper Hashtable is NULL thanks to the
# anonym function
$null -eq $ht
```

Thanks alot Guys

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you may create a `hashtable` using [`Group-Object -AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3#-ashashtable):

```sh
# Store the PIDs of all processes into a PSCustomObject, keyed by the process name
$processes = [PSCustomObject] (Get-Process -PV proc | 
                               Select-Object -Expand Id | 
                               Group-Object { $proc.Name } -AsHashtable)

# List all PIDs of given process
$processes.chrome
```

Notes:

- *[Common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3)* `-PV` (alias of `-PipelineVariable`) makes sure that we can still access the full process object from within the *[calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3)* of the `Group-Object` command, despite that we have a `Select-Object` command in between.
- The values of the properties are *arrays*, which store the process IDs of all instances of each process. E. g. `$processes.chrome` outputs a list of PIDs of all instances of the chrome process.